# BDD Visual Studio 2015 sometimes when I add new item I cannot see SpecFlow Feature File

Tags: c#, bdd, specflow, gherkin

I am trying out BDD with Specflow in Visual Studio 2015.
Previously I had created a new project and added Specflow and Nunit using NuGet Package Manager.  From the Solution Explorer I right click and select Add New Item.
From the Add New Item window I could see SpecFlow feature File, SpecFlow Hooks and SpecFlow Step Definition.

I have created a new project and when I click add new item I cannot see SpecFlow Feature File, SpecFlow Hooks and SpecFlow Step Definition. 
Am i missing a reference?
The references I can see from Solution Explorer are:
SpecRun.SpecFlowPlugin
TechTalk.SpecFlow
TechTalk.SpecRun
NUnit.VisualStudio.TestAdapter

Am I missing something?

When I click Add New Item I should be able to see SpecFlow Feature File in the add new item window.  I don't see it. It is not showing.

Thanks, Riaz

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The item templates you are looking for are in the Visual Studio Extension. You have to install it from the gallery/marketplace.

Comment: From Tools Extensions and Updates.  Found it.  Thanks for your help